# Send a message later

Tags: php, asp.net

If you have ever been to a sms messaging site, you probably have seen that users can decide they want to schedule the sending of their sms message at a later time.
So a user logs on to the site (a real life example is at http://www.smslive247.com or http://routesms.com), composes the sms and clicks on "send message at a later time" radiobox. This gives users a datetime field that you can then pick what date and time you want the message to be dispatched (as well as ability to change the timezone).
Basically, users can schedule the sending of sms.

I'm also designing a similar site and wondering if anyone can tell me how this is done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a message queue, for example in a database, that gets read by a separate process (a service, or cron job for example) that processes the records and sends the message.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen many topics on cron jobs but I've not been able to get a hold on any one that points me in the right direction. However, talking about writing a service...that sounds interesting. Can you give a link where I can get tutorials on how to do that?

Comment: @Abimbola [cron](http://clickmojo.com/code/cron-tutorial.html), [windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx).

Comment: Well, I believe challenges come from time to time for many novice programmers like me...The ability to overcome them is what make us BETTER.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a database.

Create a table with a column that contains the datetime the message should be sent, and another column with the message.

From a background thread (or even another process, such as a Windows Service or a SQL Agent task), wake up every once in a while, read the top row in the table, and see if it's time to execute it. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE MyQueue (
    TimeToExec DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Message NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO MyQueue VALUES(GETDATE(), N'message')

;WITH MYCTE AS (
  SELECT TOP 1 Message
    FROM MyQueue
    WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
      WHERE TimeToExec <= GETDATE()
      ORDER BY TimeToExec
) DELETE FROM MYCTE
  OUTPUT DELETED.Message
```

Comment: Thanks RickNZ,  Good idea. However, on a website with share hosting, you may not have the ability to do use sql Agent (especially on mysql database in php). I've tried SQL Agent on my personal db and it works. Though, I'm yet to look at windows service for ASP.net, I was looking at solving this challenge on both a PHP/MySql engine and ASP.net

Comment: What does that code do? Why not simply use a `Messages` table, containing an ID (so you won't delete messages with the same message and send time, like the 200 "Happy new year!" messages scheduled to be sent at 2012-12-31 23:59, while you only send one), a SendDateTime column and a SentDateTime one. Then your service simply selects the messages `where SentDateTime is null and SendDateTime <= Now()`, and sends them. Then it updates the successfully sent ones to set a SentDateTime, which it does by ID.

Comment: You can use the code above in your app; it doesn't have to be in SQL Agent. You can start a background worker thread, for example. @CodeCaster: the code finds the next message that's due to be sent, deletes it from the queue, and returns the message to the caller, in a single transaction. The code is only meant to broadly show how it can be done -- of course, you could include ID and/or a SentTime columns if appropriate (or write the messages to another table for archival purposes).

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to store the message and write a service to send queued messages. You can store the messages in a database.

Comment: Thanks Tundey, Can I get a reference that can point me in the right direction. Thanks